# insert json data from the twitter api then into mongodb using php

Tags: php

I have an application which sends json data to PHP script from the Twitter API so i try to convert my json data to an array and insert it into mongodb But i get the following warning:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

this is part of my code :

```
 <?php
session_start();
$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://$dbhost");
$db = $conn->$dbname;
//  // access collection
$collection = $db->tweets;
$tweet = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($tweet));
$usertimeline = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$usertimeline = json_decode($usertimeline);
// Loop array and create seperate documents for each tweet
foreach ($usertimeline as $id => $item) {
$collection->insert($item);
}
```

Comment: Please consider renaming the title of this question as it has nothing to do with mongo and little to do with twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me.
This is a part of the code,just you must be sure that you have curl support in PHP.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("twitteroauth-master/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); 
$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret,$accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);
$tweets = json_encode($tweets);
$connection = new MongoClient();
$tweetCollection = $connection->test->tweets;
$tweetCollection->insert(json_decode($tweet));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the cURL PHP documentation, [curl_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) returns true/false unless the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is set to true. Try setting that parameter to true.

Answer (score 0):

Add the option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
```

I also suggest to check for cURL and JSON parse errors.

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://$dbhost");
$db = $conn->$dbname;
// access collection
$collection = $db->tweets;
$tweet = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($tweet));
$usertimeline = curl_exec($curl);

if (curl_errno($curl) != 0) {
    // an error appeared
}

curl_close($curl);

if (($usertimeline = json_decode($usertimeline) === NULL) {
    // JSON parse error
    // empty $usertimeline or invalid JSON
    // (happens when transfer was not completely finished).
}

// Loop array and create seperate documents for each tweet
foreach ($usertimeline as $id => $item) {
    $collection->insert($item);
}
```